# Indent one level deeper rather than smart indent?

Tags: emacs, indent

When in markdown-mode, I would like to disable smart indent. Instead, when I highlight a block of code and press TAB, I would like the block to be indented one level deeper, like how Sublime does it.

What goes in my ~/.emacs to achieve this?

Comment: Could you show an example of your desired output for those of us who do not use sublime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `indent-rigidly` command to do this. I would however not recommend disabling markdown-mode's standard <kbd>TAB</kbd> binding since it does much more than indenting (for exemple it cycles visibility when point is on a header line)

For example, put this in your initialization file to bind <kbd>C-TAB</kbd> to rigid indentation:

```
(eval-after-load "markdown-mode"
  '(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "C-<tab>")
     (lambda ()
       (interactive)
       (indent-rigidly (region-beginning) (region-end) 4))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Should be working in any mode.